# macro error handling

Tags: excel, vba

I create basic macros using the Record macro button in Excel.  I then edit accordingly to make the macro do what I'm trying to do.

In this case I manually open the master.xlsx file. I then run a macro with in master.xlsx called week12.

This macro opens a file called Grant.xlsx, copies the contents of cell H16, then pastes the contents into master.xlsx cell N3.

The problem I'm having is, if the file doesn't exist I get a message to say the file can't be found, I then get a Run-time error '1004'.

The purpose of the macro is to open 40 different spreads sheets and copy the contents of a cell and paste it into master.xlsx. any one or more of the 40 files could be missing. The macro example below only shows the macro with 2 of the 40.

```
Sub Week12()
    '
    ' Week12 Macro
    '
    '   Grant

    '
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        End If

        On Error GoTo 3

        Sheets("SCORES").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        ChDir _
            "K:\\\Grant"
        Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
            "K:\\\\Week 12.xlsx"
        Range("H16").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("Master.xlsb").Activate
        Range("N3").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Range("A1").Select
        Windows("Week 12.xlsx").Activate
        ActiveWindow.Close
        GoTo 4
    3:
    'if the file is missing put a O in N3

        Range("N3").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "O"
        Range("A1").Select
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        End If
    4:
    '   Adele

        On Error GoTo 5

        Sheets("SCORES").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        ChDir _
            "K:\\\\Adele"
        Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
            "K:\\\\Adele\Week 12.xlsx"
        Range("H16").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("Master.xlsb").Activate
        Range("N4").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Range("A1").Select
        Windows("Week 12.xlsx").Activate
        ActiveWindow.Close
        GoTo 6
    5:
    'if the file is missing put a O in N4
        Range("N4").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "O"
        Range("A1").Select
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        End If
    6:
    '   Stuart Manvell

    'and so on and so on for all 40 names
end sub
```

Comment: That's a very long winded way of coding it.  Is there a pattern to where the files are stored, what info is copied and where it's pasted to? i.e. Are they all in the same folder, is it always cell H16 that's copied?  If, for example, row 1 of the Master file had the name of the file to be imported - i.e A1 = "Grant", B1="Adele" then it would be very easy to tell the code to look at each name in row 1, open that workbook and paste the result below, or open each XL file in a certain folder and copy the contents out.

Answer (score 2):

Try the Following, you will need to adapt it to your needs though.

```
'Some Other Script here


'Ignore errors to allow for error evaluation
On Error Resume Next

ExcelFilePAth = "INSERT FILE PATH HERE"

'YAYAYA is just a random name
'Purpose is to generate an error if the File Path doesnt exisit
YAYAYA = GetAttr(ExcelFilePAth)

Select Case Err.Number

'If the File Path is valid the Error Number should be 0
'Else it will present an error message and then continue

    Case Is = 0

        'Insert your Script for processing the Excel Sheets Here

    Case Else


        'Insert what to do here

        MsgBox "The File path below doesnt exisit:" & vbNewLine & _
                vbNewLine & _
                ExcelFilePAth

End Select

'Resume error checking
On Error GoTo 0

'Some Other Script here
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot set up an entire work environment but there were some obvious areas in your code where procedures could be looped. The collection of names could be stuffed into a large array and this provides the extents of the loop. For each iteration, a new name is used in the folder name where the workbook is opened from.

```
Sub anyWQeek()
    Dim thisWeek As Long
    thisWeek = 12   '<~~ used below as Week & wk
    Weekly wk:=thisWeek 
End Sub

Sub Weekly(Optional wk As Long = 1)
    Dim v As Long, vNAMEs As Variant, var As Variant
    Dim nwb As Workbook, twb As Workbook

    Set twb = ThisWorkbook

    vNAMEs = Array("Grant", "Adelle", "Stuart", "Manville", _
                   "abc", "lorem", "ipsum", "blah", _
                   "blah-blah", "blah-blah-blah", "blh", "blah2")
                    'and so on and so on for all 40 names

    On Error GoTo bm_NextWorkbook

    For v = LBound(vNAMEs) To UBound(vNAMEs)
        var = 0
        ChDir "K:\\\" & vNAMEs(v)   '<~~ e.g. Grant
        Set nwb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="K:\\\" & vNAMEs(v) & "\Week " & wk & ".xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
        var = nwb.Worksheets(1).Range("H16").Value
        nwb.Close savechanges:=False
bm_NextWorkbook:
        twb.Sheets("SCORES").Range("N3").Offset(v, 0) = var
    Next v

End Sub
```

The zero or the value from H16 were going to the same place so I set a variant to **0** and only overrode that var if everything went according to plan. In any event, the value gets written into a cell offset from N3 by the iteration of the loop.

I wasn't entirely sure what worksheet the value from H16 was coming from so I simply chose `Worksheets(1)`.

Comment: Yes I have no coding experience, so I just give it ago and as you say it's a very long method. In general I get away with it, as it is only to help me in my work and no one else uses them. It's going to take me a bit of time to understand all your help. I will get back when I've got it, but am sure your patience might be tested.  Many thanks